# What is the purpose of passing CancellationToken to Task.Factory.StartNew()

Tags: task-parallel-library, .net-4.5, cancellation, cancellation-token

In the following code a `CancellationToken` is passed to the `.StartNew(,)` method as the 2nd parameter, but is only usable by the `Action` via the closure in the lambda.  So, what is the purpose of passing the token through the `.StartNew(,)` method's 2nd parameter?

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = cts.Token;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{
    while (true)
    {
        // simulate doing something useful
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}, token);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`StartNew` method schedules a task in the tread pool, but not necessary start it right at the moment, because threads may be unavailable. During waiting for the start the cancellation request may occur, after which the thread pool wouldn't start a task at all. After task was started it's your job to handle cancellation of the task.

Comment: Both this answer and Haukinger's answer are correct, yet incomplete. You should expand this answer with Haukinger's input since this is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, the purpose of the `CancellationToken` passed to `Task.Run` and `Taskfactory.StartNew` is to allow the task to differentiate *being cancelled* by an exception thrown from `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested` and *failing* because of any other exception.

That is, if the `CancellationToken` passed at start throws, the task's state is `Cancelled` while any other exception (even from another `CancellationToken`) will set it to `Faulted`.

Also, if the `CancellationToken` is cancelled *before* the task actually starts, it won't be started at all.